# UITableView in Swift - dequeueing of cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BookCell") as BookTableViewCell

        println("ip: \(indexPath.row)")
        cell.bookLabel.text = "Row #\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
```

I just see one cell, with the text overwritten 5 times, instead of 5 cells. I thought we didn't have to do the if (!cell) nonsense anymore? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: works fine, same as old good "nonsense" did.

Comment: did u mess up auto layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing the UILabels overwritten 5 times, it is because your cell height has not been defined and it is being computed as 0 pixels tall. Any one of the following should help you explicitly or implicitly define the row height:

1) Set the row height within Interface Builder:

[image]

2) Implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}
```

3) Set Auto Layout constraints between your cell's `UILabel` and the outer boundaries of the `UITableViewCell`:

[image]